# Import js library vue cli + webpack

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack

I'm trying to import js library to use it in a Vue component.

From CDNs all js imports are working. But i can't use CDN for production.

if i use the  way to import it globally i can see that my js file is replaced with html content... i guess it is because of a bad webpack config.

I also used the require('') way directly in my component but no success.

the only JS that is imported is app.js, but i can't find any config file that is calling this js or any webpack config that tells to merge js files in it...

Comment: Please add webpack config and example import.

Comment: Also add the errors you see on console while either building or opening the application. Also add which library you want to import as they might work differently to others.

Answer (score 0):

i have a vue.config.js file like this i can't find any other config file for webpack in my project

```
module.exports = {
    // proxy API requests to Valet during development
    devServer: {
        //proxy: 'http://api.mtm'
    },
    indexPath: 'public/index.html',
}
```

to import js file i've tried like this directly in my Vue component just after the export default {..

```
require('../../public/timer.js');
```

the error i have looks like that : TypeError: t is undefined